# Unity 2019.3.0f6 Gradle Build failed

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, build.gradle

I am trying to build the VRTK v4 Hand Tracking Example for Oculus Quest

While building the Gradle I get this error what I don't really get what it wants me to do:

```
Win32Exception: ApplicationName='C:/Program Files/Unity/Hub/Editor/2019.3.0f6/Editor/Data/PlaybackEngines/AndroidPlayer\OpenJDK\bin\java.exe', CommandLine='-Xmx4096m -classpath "C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2019.3.0f6\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\Tools\gradle\lib\gradle-launcher-5.1.1.jar" org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain assembleDebug -x validateSigningDebug', CurrentDirectory='C:/Users/BP/Documents/Unity Projects/Oculus-Quest-VRTK-master/Assets../Temp\OVRGradleExport\OculusHands', Native error= Der Verzeichnisname ist ungültig.

 System.Diagnostics.Process.StartWithCreateProcess (System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo) (at <ae22a4e8f83c41d69684ae7f557133d9>:0)
 System.Diagnostics.Process.Start () (at <ae22a4e8f83c41d69684ae7f557133d9>:0)
 (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) System.Diagnostics.Process.Start()
 OculusBuildApp.BuildGradleProject () (at Assets/Oculus/VR/Editor/OVRBuild.cs:363)
 OculusBuildApp.OVRBuildRun () (at Assets/Oculus/VR/Editor/OVRBuild.cs:281)
 OculusBuildApp+<>c.<StartBuildAndRun>b__29_0 () (at Assets/Oculus/VR/Editor/OVRBuild.cs:257)
 System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context (System.Object state) (at <437ba245d8404784b9fbab9b439ac908>:0)
 System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal (System.Threading.ExecutionContext executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, System.Object state, System.Boolean preserveSyncCtx) (at <437ba245d8404784b9fbab9b439ac908>:0)
 System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run (System.Threading.ExecutionContext executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, System.Object state, System.Boolean preserveSyncCtx) (at <437ba245d8404784b9fbab9b439ac908>:0)
 System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run (System.Threading.ExecutionContext executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, System.Object state) (at <437ba245d8404784b9fbab9b439ac908>:0)
 System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart () (at <437ba245d8404784b9fbab9b439ac908>:0)
 UnityEngine.<>c:<RegisterUECatcher>b__0_0(Object, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs)
```

Comment: Well, first use the latest version if you're not on a LTS one

Comment: you mean of unity?
i prefer not to switch versions all the time because except for the gradle building it works fine

Comment: @Remy is that a unity thing too along with various other interesting characters like é that cant be in paths?

Comment: @Remy well, there is no real folder called `Assets../` and i thought that it's just displaying that there are more folders... neither inside the project nor in the Temp folder

Comment: Sorry my previous comment was incorrect! It may not be the fullstop (as I thought it was) but rather the whitespaces. I think the Android SDK/NDK doesn't play well with it. (IIRC Android studio also prompts a warning about whitespaces in filenames).

Comment: @Remy so you think it's the folder `Unity Projects`?   And have you any idea why it's not a problem with all my other projects prior in this folder? the assets are all with their normal names -> is there a reasonable way to check for this problem fast?

Comment: FYI: Changed the folder `Unity Projects` to `Unity-Projects` just for testing and still have this problem

Comment: Hmm, not sure what could be invalid about that path then.. Do you have any characters with umlauts or other accents in your file path as @BugFinder mentioned? (I'm just trying to go off the error here which states the path is invalid and trying to think of possibilities that may cause invalid paths, and can't replicate it so can't really test it myself either) I also notice the path doesn't end in a file extension `OVRGradleExport\OculusHands`, maybe that has something to do with it?

Comment: @Remy did you tested it with this example, too? [link](https://github.com/FusedVR/Oculus-Quest-VRTK)   i have no custom scripts added, so there should'nt be any umlauts or so...   if you need any further info let me know -> normal building internal and sideloading the apk works fine; it's really just the gradle-stuff that's broken  and the missing file extension is confusing me, too

Comment: Does the directory it mentions exist?

Comment: not really...    the Temp folder is on the same level as the Assets folder https://imgur.com/yj0oQEj

Comment: Now tested it again on a separate machine with a different folder etc.but still the same problem